# Inconsistancy between Meta and Main reputation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just noticed that my reputation in "Physics Meta" is differs from "Physics" (slightly lower) is this a bug or I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reputation is copied over from the main site to the meta site once per hour, it isn't always kept in sync. So this is to be expected, and the number will catch up soon.